# How to use formdata in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want sending formdata including objects in objects

```
let submit_obj = { test : { kor : "korea" , eng : "usa"} }
let test_form = new FormData();
test_form.append(test, submit_obj );

    $.ajax({
        url : '/api/filesave',
        type : 'post',
        dataType : 'josn',
        data : test_form,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success: function(res){
            console.log('res',res);
        }                   
    });
```

and API response

```
req.body = Object { test : "[object Object]" }
```

How to extract the test value??
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Why are you using Form Data with an Object? Do you want to pass the object up to the server in one piece? jQuery handles it for you without FormData...

Comment: What data format does the backend code expect? How is it attempting to use the data from the request?

Comment: there is a typo - `dataType : 'josn',`

Comment: I would like to send this information along with the image file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) will convert value to string. In that case `test : "[object Object]"` is absolutly correct value;
So, You can try to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
test_form.append(test, JSON.stringify(submit_obj));
```

or [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob):

```js
test_form.append(test, new Blob([JSON.stringify(submit_obj)], {type:'application/json'}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use dataType = JSON.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/filesave',
    data: test_form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```